# Broadcom BCM4312 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

New to Ubuntu on a Dell computer.

Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't see my wireless card (broadcom bcm4312) at all, the wireless light doesnt light.  The driver is listed under "additional drivers", but fails when i attempt to install.

I have tried responses to other questions, no results.  Just learning-not yet an expert with coding.

Comment: try to follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 0):

Please run the terminal command:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with the backslash. Is your wireless device enumerated 14e4:4315? If so, please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us know how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  Because my computer did not support wired internet (it is a thin model; to thin for a "thick" RJ45) --> no port, I had to be "creative":

I had to go back to windows (or another computer, whatever), search the internet for "bcmwl-kernel-source.deb" and download a recent copy and then put it on a USB drive (or store it on the windows partition, you know, anywhere linux can get at it.)

Then, on Linux, open the file with Ubuntu Software Center.  (Right click in file explorer... open with... Ubuntu Software Center)

Let it install.  Ignore warnings.

Now, with software center open, go to the top of screen --> Edit --> Software Sources --> Additional Drivers tab --> you should now be able to turn on your wireless drivers.
*These instructions are for Ubuntu 13, so I hope the interface for Software center is same on 12 :O.o